# What is right way to ref angular2 files for distribution in prod hosted on an IIS server and bundle with gulp

Tags: typescript, angular, gulp

I keep finding articles about building angular2 for production but it's still eluding me.

I've started with the angular2-bare-bones project.

**structure**

```
/node_modules
/src/
----/app/ <- *.ts and *.js compiled files are here
----/images/
----/js/ <- custom js files here
----/styles/ custom css here
----index.html
----systemjs.config.js
----typings.d.ts
/typings/
```

I've created my gulp tasks to copy the html files and bundle my js files into a /dist/ folder. I've tried bundling each angular2 package's /node_modules/@angular/xxx/bundle/xxx.umd.min.js files.  I feel like maybe I'm doing this incorrectly.  Is there a better way using gulp to compile the @angular node_module packages into a distribution folder?

I'm using "gulp-bundle-assets" and my goal is to host the angular2 site via IIS and not with npm.